# Issues creating 100% height divs using display: table-cell in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a two-column, full-screen magazine viewer, with a fixed width banner on the left. The right column will be responsive.

Utilising the display:table; method I have created the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/pouncebounce/pTeBP/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tbl_con">
   <div class="tbl_row">
      <div class="tbl_cell" id="banner">
      </div>
      <div class="tbl_cell" id="publication">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   var viewer = new com.zmags.api.Viewer();
   viewer.setPublicationID("b129d2b8");
   viewer.setParentElementID("publication");
   viewer.show();
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.tbl_con {
display: table;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
*height: 100%;
}

.tbl_row {
display: table-row;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
*height: 100%;
}

.tbl_cell {
display: table-cell;
min-height: 100%;
*height: 100%;  
}

#banner {
width: 200px;
background-color: #1E90FF;
border-right: solid 3px #fff;
}

#publication {
width: *;
background-color: #FFAB1E;
}
```

This displays correctly in the latest version of IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox, where the 100% heights, or the actual magazine, do not appear at all. Any reason why?

Comment: Are you using `*height` to indicate something? If I change it to `height: 100%` is works fine in Firefox. I don't see why you'd need a `min-height` here.

Comment: As simple as that? Wow, thanks! I was using CSS-tricks.com article on the `display: table` method, and it said parent divs require a height and children require a min-height with a *height <IE7 fallback. Thanks!

Comment: Test it in IE7 to be sure. If it doesn't work in IE6 I wouldn't be too worried (I don't even have an IE6 test machine anymore).

Comment: Apparently our magazine viewer doesn't even work before IE8 anyway, so that fix works perfectly... thank you!

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Put that as an answer so he cant accept it. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `*height` to `height` and remove `min-height`.

Make sure you test in IE7, but it should work.